# How to save images to different directories based on conditions while in a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to save different images to different directories based on a condition. Images are generated in a for loop. What code can do this?

I've tried to put a if statement but that did not work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

for i in range(z):
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  plt.show()

  #Conditions
  df.iloc["column"] = 1  ##Condition 1
  df.iloc["column"] = 2  ##Condition 2

  if df.iloc["column"] = 1
       #puts image in directory 1 when condition 1 is met
       elseif  if df.iloc["column"] = 2 #puts image in directory 2 when condition 2 is met

#This saves the file to a particular file directory
directory1 = "file path to directory 1"
directory2 = "file path to directory 2"

fig.savefig(directory1 + str(i) +".png")
fig.savefig(directory2 + str(i) +".png")
```

I expect the output to save the images in each of the 2 folders based on condition 1 and condition 2

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of syntax errors in your if statement; this is the corrected statement:

```
if df.iloc["column"] == 1:
   #puts image in directory 1 when condition 1 is met
elif df.iloc["column"] == 2:
   #puts image in directory 2 when condition 2 is met
```

First error: indentation (`elif` must be under the same column of the `if`).
Second error: `=` instead of `==`
Third error: `elseif` instead of `elif`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insight and that helps out a lot. Yeah, there were a lot of errors. this clarifies things